# How to make a good loop for this query result

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I've got a query that gives me something like the following result when I would print out a table:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    ID      |    Name     |    Color      |     Size     |    Qty    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1       |    First    |    Green      |      S       |     1     |
|    2       |    First    |    Green      |      L       |     2     |
|    3       |    First    |    Green      |      XL      |     1     |
|    4       |    First    |    Red        |      M       |     2     |
|    5       |    First    |    Red        |      L       |     3     |
|    6       |    Second   |    Blue       |      S       |     1     |
|    7       |    Second   |    Blue       |      M       |     4     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I want to make an overview (in real life these are products) where someone can click a button to edit or delete. I want to loop over it with a foreach loop or something and print it out something like this:

```
+========================================================================+
|    Name     |    Color      |     Size     |    Qty    |    Action     |
+========================================================================+
|    First    |    Green      |      S       |     1     |  Edit|Delete  |
|             |               |      L       |     2     |  Edit|Delete  |
|             |               |      XL      |     1     |  Edit|Delete  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    First    |    Red        |      M       |     2     |  Edit|Delete  |
|             |               |      L       |     3     |  Edit|Delete  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    Second   |    Blue       |      S       |     1     |  Edit|Delete  |
|             |               |      M       |     4     |  Edit|Delete  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

but somehow I just can't get my head around how I would program this loop. Or should I change the query?
I hope someone can help. If you need more information, please tell me.

Comment: this is handled on the view Edit and Delete should be anchors that should point some controller method where you can edit or delete. Also provide id of each record as third parameter in the anchor and get it using this->uri->segment(3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some of this in the database which could well make it easier to display the data in your code:

```
select 
    group_concat(ID) as id, 
    name, 
    color, 
    group_concat(size) as size, 
    group_concat(qty) as qty 
from 
    myTable
group by
    name,
    color
```

The result would look like this:

```
ID     | name  | color | size   | qty
1,2,3  | First | Green | S,L,XL | 1,2,1
etc...
```

Now in your code, this makes it much easier to output the way you would like it to.

```
echo "<table>";
while($row=someFetchFromDatabase($results))
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['color']."</td>";
    $temp=explode($row['size']);
    echo "<td>";
    foreach($temp as $val)
    {
        echo $val."<br>";
    }
    echo "</td>";
    $temp=explode($row['qty']);
    echo "<td>";
    foreach($temp as $val)
    {
        echo $val."<br>";
    }
    echo "</td>";
    $temp=explode($row['IDs']);
    echo "<td>";
    foreach($temp as $val)
    {
        echo "<a href='someLink.php?action=edit&ID=".$val."'>Edit</a> | <a href='someLink.php?action=delete&ID=".$val."'>Delete</a>";
    }
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>'
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick!. I knew it would be a pretty easy solution. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do anything to the query.

In pseudo code (I don't speak PHP)...

```
variables $name = "", $colour = "";
for (every row)    
    if (row.name = $name) and (row.colour = $colour)
        display nothing for name and colour
    else
        display row.name
        display row.colour
        $name = row.name
        $colour = row.colour
```